# Can I customize kakfa producer's reconnection interval to brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

As I know, kafka producer reconnect over brokers with certain interval. This behavior achieves both of reducing connections and balancing data volume of partitions.

There are two questions.

1. Can I customize the interval of reconnect.
2. If I configure authentication on broker, every (re)connection establishment to broker requires authentication?

Actually I worry about LDAP server's overhead. If many connection leads more overhead to LDAP server, then customizing reconnection interval can be a solution.

Comment: Kafka client is able to close the socket channels if they keep idle for a specific period of time (set by `connections.max.idle.ms`). Is it what you mean by `reconnect interval`?

Comment: @amethystic Thank for comment but connections.max.idle.ms property is not solution for me. I concluded that there's no config exactly I want.

Comment: Seems that `reconnect.backoff.ms` is what you are searching for.